# Plugin for Qgis that will have a feature to open the attribute table with the selected layers

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-table

I'm developing a plugin for QGIS that will have a feature open
the attribute table with the selected layers.

I split the code into two python files.

This is my code.

#### First file:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
from TabelaAt import TabelaAtributos
from open_attribute_table_dialog import OpenAttributeTableDialog

import resources

import os.path

class OpenAttributeTable:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'OpenAttributeTable_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)


        # Declare instance attributes
        #self.actions = []
        #self.menu = self.tr(u'&OpenAT')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'OpenAttributeTable')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'OpenAttributeTable')
    
    def createToolButton(self, parent, text):
        #criar a ferramenta de botoes
        button = QToolButton(parent)
        button.setObjectName(text)
        button.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        button.setPopupMode(QToolButton.MenuButtonPopup)
        parent.addWidget(button)
        return button
    
    def createAction(self, icon_path, text, callback):
        #cria acao
        action = QAction(
            QIcon(icon_path),
            text,
            self.iface.mainWindow())
        action.setCheckable(True)
        action.toggled.connect(callback)
        return action
    
    def initGui(self):
        self.actionCriar = self.createAction(":/plugins/OpenAttributeTable/icon.png", 
                                             u"Abrir Tabela de Atributos",
                                             self.run)
        
        self.tool = TabelaAtributos(self.iface.mapCanvas(), self.actionCriar)
        
        self.selectionButton = self.createToolButton(self.toolbar, u'OpenAttributeTableButton')
        self.selectionButton.addAction(self.actionCriar)
        self.selectionButton.setDefaultAction(self.actionCriar)
        
    
    def openTable(self, b):
        self.actionCriar.setChecked(False)
        self.selectionButton.setDefaultAction(self.selectionButton.sender())
        if b:
            self.iface.mapCanvas().setDefaultAction(self.toolTable)
        else:
            self.iface.mapCanvas().unsetMapTool(self.toolTable)
        
    def unload(self):
        self.iface.mainWindow().removeToolBar(self.toolbar)

    def run(self, b):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        self.selectionButton.setDefaultAction(self.selectionButton.sender())
        if b:
            self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.tool)
        else:
            self.iface.mapCanvas().unsetMapTool(self.tool)
```

#### Second file:

```
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.Qt import *
from qgis.utils import iface
 class TabelaAtributos(QgsMapTool):
    
    def __init__(self, canvas, action):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.active = False
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.setAction(action)
        
    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        dv = QgsDualView()
        dv.init( iface.activeLayer(), iface.mapCanvas() )
        dv.setView( QgsDualView.AttributeEditor )
        dv.show()
        
        
    def deactivate(self):
        if self is not None:
            QgsMapTool.deactivate(self)
        
    def activate(self):
        QgsMapTool.activate(self)
```

I do not know why, but I'm having a mistake.

Comment: whats the mistake? please post the error message as well

Comment: I probably did not express myself well by using the expression error.

Basically I select, a certain area from a layer, but when
I click on the plugin button it doesn't open the attributes table.

I think there will be some error in my code that causes it not to open the table attributes.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works but this "dialog" close immediately,for fix it need create a custom dialog and add the `QgsDualView` widget.

Check this example:
https://github.com/alfanugraha/lumens_ui/blob/f8e5e209018b4ff0adc1083abb9e61915df508da/dialog_layer_attribute_dualview.py

**Example using your code:**

```
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.Qt import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from qgis.utils import iface

class DualViewDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(DualViewDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

class TabelaAtributos(QgsMapTool):

    def __init__(self, canvas, action):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.active = False
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.setAction(action)

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        dlg = DualViewDialog()
        dv = QgsDualView()
        dv.init( iface.activeLayer(), iface.mapCanvas() )
        dv.setView( QgsDualView.AttributeEditor )
        dlg.layout.addWidget(dv)
        dlg.exec_()         

    def deactivate(self):
        if self is not None:
            QgsMapTool.deactivate(self)

    def activate(self):
        QgsMapTool.activate(self)
```

**Tested using QGIS 2.18.15**